# Count occurence of vector in another vector

Tags: r, data-analysis

```
tweet<- c("boy","girl","boy","x")
unique_words<- c("asdfdd","boy","girl","ahmed","asdf","asfeertrt")
word_count<-table(tweet[tweet %in%unique_words])
word_occurence<- as.integer(unique_words%in% tweet)
```

I got these outputs: 
   word_count ::

```
          boy girl 
           2    1
```

word_occurence ::

```
           0 1 1 0 0 0
```

but I would like the output to be as the following:
  0 2 1 0 0 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do following:

```
library(stringr)
rowSums(sapply(tweet, function(x, y) str_count(x, y), unique_words))
[1] 0 2 1 0 0 0
```

The command loops through the `tweet` vector, counts each occurence (`str_count()`; `stringr` package) and then sums up the data using rowSums.

Comment: This can be written in a more compact form: `rowSums(sapply(tweet, str_count, unique_words))`

Comment: Or another option is `colSums(sapply(unique_words, grepl, tweet))`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(unique_words%in% tweet, word_count, 0)
#[1] 0 1 2 0 0 0
```